# htaccess blocking jpg but not jpeg

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to allow all images in a directory to be accessible. Right now I can only get PNGs to display, and JPGs show a broken icon. If I put the absolute jpg link into the address bar, I get a 403 error.

Been wracking my brains for hours trying to get this to work. I'm obviously missing something totally obvious. Can anyone help me get this right?

Here is the htaccess file, which is located in the directory. The jpgs are in directory/img/ (I tried moving them into the directory but they still didn't load)

```
Options +Indexes

<FilesMatch "(\.(png|jpg|gif)|~)$">
  Order allow,deny
  Allow From All
  Satisfy All
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: If you rename your .htaccess does your `.jpg` file work?

Comment: No, then nothing displays. But with the htaccess I have, I can display png/gif/jpeg but not jpg

Answer (score 0):

Try: `<FilesMatch "(\.(png|jpg|gif)|~)$">`

Comment: Thanks, but no, it makes no difference.

Comment: Do gif work fine? what is the exact extension of your jpg? .jpg or .jpeg?

Comment: if .jpeg works better changing your question to _htaccess blocking jpg but not jpeg_

Comment: is jpg file isn't corrupted? did you checked the upper/lower case in the file path and name for its url?

Comment: Amended question title. No the jpg files are not corrupt. Filenames are checked...

Answer (score 0):

`Options +Indexes
RewriteEngine on

<FilesMatch "(\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)|~)$">
  Order allow,deny
  Allow From All
  Satisfy All

</FilesMatch>`


Get this to `.htaccess` folder, where you have images.